# Polymer - How to data-bind paper-dropdown menu selections to fill another's

Tags: data-binding, polymer

I have a dynamic form that's using `<core-ajax>` to bind data into multiple `<paper-dropdown-menu>`'s. My question: What is the preferred way to change the data in each dropdown based upon the previous one's selection. Right now, there is no javascript for it, only Polymer data-binding. Here is the code:

```html
<polymer-element name="example-element" attributes="">
  <template>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="example-element.css">
    
    <core-ajax auto
     url="http://example.json"
     response="{{regionData}}"
     handleAs="json">
    </core-ajax>

    <!-- global user object -->
    <pvc-globals id="globals" values="{{globals}}"></pvc-globals>

    <!-- page container -->
    <div class="background" vertical layout>
      <!-- toolbar -->
      <template is="auto-binding">


      <!-- Add teams dialog -->
      <paper-action-dialog heading="Add A Example" backdrop autoCloseDisabled
        id="addTeamDialog">
        <p>Once this form is complete, you will have a new example on your account.</p>
        <br>

        <!-- Region Name -->
        <paper-dropdown-menu label="Choose Your Region" style="width: 100%;">
            <paper-dropdown class="dropdown">
                <core-menu class="menu" selected="{{selection}}">
                    <template repeat="{{region in regionData}}">
                        <paper-item name="{{region.name}}">{{region.name}}</paper-item>
                    </template>
                </core-menu>
            </paper-dropdown>
        </paper-dropdown-menu>

        <br><br>

        <!-- State Name depending on what region you choose -->
        <paper-dropdown-menu label="Choose Your State" style="width: 100%;">
            <paper-dropdown class="dropdown">
                <core-menu class="menu">
                    <template ref="{{region.name}}" repeat="{{region, regionIndex in regionData}}">
                        <paper-item>{{region.states[regionIndex]}}</paper-item>
                    </template>
                </core-menu>
            </paper-dropdown>
        </paper-dropdown-menu>

        <br><br>

        <!-- Club Name -->
        <paper-dropdown-menu label="Choose Your Club depending on what region you choose" style="width: 100%;">
            <paper-dropdown class="dropdown">
                <core-menu class="menu">
                    <template repeat="{{region, regionIndex in regionData}}">
                      <template repeat="{{clubs in region.clubs}}">
                        <paper-item>{{clubs.name}}</paper-item>
                      </template>
                    </template>
                </core-menu>
            </paper-dropdown>
        </paper-dropdown-menu>

        <br><br>

        <!-- Team Name -->
        <paper-dropdown-menu label="Choose Your Team" style="width: 100%;">
            <paper-dropdown class="dropdown">
                <core-menu class="menu">
                    <template repeat="{{region, regionIndex in regionData}}">
                      <template repeat="{{clubs in region.clubs}}">
                        <paper-item>{{clubs.teams[regionIndex]}}</paper-item>
                      </template>
                    </template>
                </core-menu>
            </paper-dropdown>
        </paper-dropdown-menu>

        <!-- <paper-input-decorator label="Your Team Name" floatingLabel
          error="Team Name is required!" autovalidate>
            <input is="core-input" type="text" value="{{teamName}}" required>
        </paper-input-decorator> -->

        <paper-button dismissive on-tap="{{openInfo}}">More Info...</paper-button>
        <paper-button affirmative>Cancel</paper-button>
        <paper-button affirmative>Add Team</paper-button>
      </paper-action-dialog>


      <!-- more info dialog (At time, adding `backdrop` attr to this caused error on close) -->
      <paper-dialog heading="More Info For Adding Teams" transition="core-transition-top" 
        id="infoDialog">
        <p>If you're region or team is missing, please email us at 
          <a href="mailto:info@mintonette.io">info@mintonette.io</a> so we can contact the
          neccessary region/authorities to request your addition to join our community!</p>
      </paper-dialog>


      <!-- toast -->
      <paper-toast id="toast1" text="{{message}}" onclick="discardDraft(el)"></paper-toast>
    </div>
  </template>


  <script src="example-element.js"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I feel to be the most 'Polymer-way' possible to this question (until a Polymer team member answers it). Once you have access to your JSON data via `<core-ajax>` element, then bind and loop through it in your `<paper-dropdown-menu>` like so:

```
<core-ajax auto
   url="http://jsonexample.com/example.json"
   response="{{yourData}}"
   handleAs="json">
</core-ajax>

<!-- Region Name -->
    <paper-dropdown-menu label="Your Label" style="width: 100%;">
        <paper-dropdown class="dropdown">
            <core-menu class="menu" selected="{{selection}}" on-core-select="{{DDSelected}}">
                <template repeat="{{something in yourData}}">
                    <paper-item name="{{something.name}}">{{something.name}}</paper-item>
                </template>
            </core-menu>
        </paper-dropdown>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Notice that on the `<core-menu>` element there is the `on-core-selected` attribute that binds to a function in our script, which looks like this:

```
regionSelected: function(e) {
      var convert = [];
      // save selected item
      this.item = this.DDSelection;

      // Loop through ajax data to find obj selected that matches selection
      for (var i = 0; i <= this.yourData.length - 1; i++) {

        if (this.yourData[i].name === this.item) {
          this.yourObj = this.yourData[i];
          // convert obj to array b/c Polymer doesn't loop -> obj
          convert.push(this.yourObj);
          this.convert = convert;
        }

      }
    }
```

What this is basically doing is taking the selection that the user chose and looping through your ajax data to find a matching property name. Once it has, then convert that object into an array (if necessary). This is crucial because as of now, Polymer only loops through arrays - not objects. Then, store it as a variable called `convert`

Once you do this, in your next dropdown, loop through `convert` and you are golden:

```
...
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Choose Your Second" style="width: 100%;" 
   disabled?="{{!selection}}">
       <paper-dropdown class="dropdown">
           <core-menu class="menu">
               <template repeat="{{key, index in convert}}">
                   <template repeat="{{prop in key.props}}">
                      <paper-item>{{prop}}</paper-item>
                   </template>
                </template>
           </core-menu>
       </paper-dropdown>
 </paper-dropdown-menu>
```

A good UX move is to also disable the dropdown until the first has been selected. Notice the `disabled?="{{selection}}"` attribute on the `<paper-dropdown-menu>` element which is doing that...

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example of dependent(cascading) drop-down's: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/gucasa/1/edit?html,console,output)

It is commented, but shortly this is what it does:

- it assumes that there is saved state(in the DB) and at load it
  initiate the drop-downs according to that state.
- it catches selection changes(for storing them after).

Comment: This definitely works, but surely there is a more Polymer-specific design to do this with less logic and more data-binding? Also, I'm using specifically the `<paper-dropdown-menu>` which has a little different binding rules than the default `<select>` element.